# How to center align element in mobile version?

Tags: css, mobile

I tried to modify some element with the following text "Connect with Deepak" in [my page](http://www.deepakmaddila.com/) but without little luck. Please help me to edit the CSS:

```
@media (max-width:560px)  {
.vc_sep_holder .vc_sep_holder_l   {
 max-width: 320px; 
 margin:auto;
}}

@media (max-width:560px)  {
 .vc_sep_holder .vc_sep_holder_r   { 
  max-width: 320px; 
  margin:auto;
}}
```

The two line always appear in mobile. Can someone provide advice to where I make mistake?

Comment: add `text-align: center` to `.vc_separator h4 {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your media query: `.vc_separator.vc_sep_double {width:100%;}`

Comment: I tryed, but dont change nothing.

Comment: It must be done on the actual H4 element.  Not on the container, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Still nothing.. 

i tryed this:

`@media (max-width:560px)  {
.h4   {
 max-width: 320px; 
 margin: 0px auto;
}}

@media (max-width:560px)  {
 .h4   { 
  max-width: 320px; 
  margin: 0px auto;
}}`

Comment: I want to be in 1 row, instead of 2.

Comment: No. Text is in two rows. Need to be in 1 row.

Comment: Does this fix your problem? add this in your media query:  .vc_separator.vc_sep_double {width:100%;}

Comment: Check this image, to see what i talking about. 

http://i.imgur.com/7HxHRwB.png?1

Comment: Updated my original answer incase you want to mark that as a working answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying `margin: 0px auto`

Edit:

`.vc_separator.vc_sep_double .vc_sep_line {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}`

Comment: I tryed: 

`@media (max-width:560px)  {
.vc_sep_holder .vc_sep_holder_l   {
 max-width: 320px; 
 margin: 0px auto;
}}

@media (max-width:560px)  {
 .vc_sep_holder .vc_sep_holder_r   { 
  max-width: 320px; 
  margin: 0px auto;
}}`

But not changed nothing.

Comment: You are running on WordPress engine. "Connect with Deepak" is centered. What seem to be the problem?

Comment: Need to be in 1 row, instead of 2 rows.

Comment: Try. ```.vc_separator.vc_sep_double .vc_sep_line { border-bottom: 0px; }```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue. Thanks to everyone !

```
@media (max-width:560px)  {
.vc_separator.vc_sep_double {width:100%;}
}
```